# how do I add just MMYY using SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar

```
UPDATE Customer SET CurrentDiscount='30',Company=CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(),3)
```

I would like to just add MMYY format using SQL script.
Above script writing MM/DD/YY format.

Can anyone help me with this? Couldn't find just for MMYY format on web...

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FORMAT Function as follows

```
UPDATE Customer SET CurrentDiscount='30',Company=FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substrings or in your case `right()`:

```
UPDATE Customer
    SET CurrentDiscount = '30',
        Company = REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 3), 5), '/', '');
```

Type 3 should be in the format DD/MM/YY.  The last five characters are basically what you want, minus the slash.

Answer (score 0):

You can `CONVERT` your date to `MM/DD/YY` and then using `STUFF` to remove `/DD/`

```
UPDATE Customer
SET CurrentDiscount = '30',
    Company = STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(), 111), 3, 6, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the best answer there is but at least you can try.

```
UPDATE Customer SET CurrentDiscount='30',Company=CONVERT(varchar(8), SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()))<2 THEN
    '0'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(1),DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()))
   ELSE
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()))
   END +
  substring(Convert(varchar(4),DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE())),3,2),3)
```

I really don't know what this script is for. But I hope this helps. Gambare!